# What Does The Random String In URI Of A PlayList In Spotify Stand For

Tags: spotify

I am currently integrating Spotify with our music player app. So I visited the official site of Spotify and studied its tutorial.

But when I came across code:

```
-(void)playUsingSession:(SPTSession *)session 
{
    // Create a new player if needed
    if (self.player == nil) 
    {
       self.player = [[SPTAudioStreamingController alloc] initWithClientId:[SPTAuth defaultInstance].clientID];
    }



    [self.player loginWithSession:session callback:^(NSError *error)           
    {

        if (error != nil) 
        {
            NSLog(@"*** Logging in got error: %@", error);

            return;
        }

        NSURL *trackURI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify:track:58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp"];

        [self.player playURIs:@[ trackURI ] fromIndex:0 callback:^(NSError *error) 
        {
           if (error != nil) 
           {
               NSLog(@"*** Starting playback got error: %@", error);

               return;
           }
       }];
   }];
}
```

I don't know what **"58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp"** in this line means

```
NSURL *trackURI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify:track:58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp"];
```

Is it the id of the track?

Because it is hardcoded, so I don't know how could I request it.

I read the documentation of the APIs especially on the part of SPTPlaylists. But I can't find any explanation of what this string stands for.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, `58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp` is the Spotify ID for the track, and `spotify:track:58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp` is its Spotify URI. There is some information in the [Spotify Web API User Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#spotify-uris-ids) about how identifiers for the Spotify catalog work.

You can use the Spotify desktop client to find out the ID/URI of an album, artist, track or playlist by right-clicking on the header of the view that shows its contents, or you can use the [Web API Search endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) to find out these identifier.

We have just updated the [iOS SDK Tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/) to explain better where this ID comes from.

Comment: This is the tutorial I followed, but I didn't see any explanation about that ID. Anyway thank you, I can see now what that ID is for, but only the Web API can be used to find out these IDs? Or even one of the methods of the SDK can also be used to find out these IDs?

Comment: @EpicNinja we have just added that explanation to the tutorial, that's why you didn't see it when you read it. Yes, you can use [these methods in SPTSearch](https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTSearch.html) from the SDK that are basically  handy wrappers around the Web API Search endpoint.

Comment: Hi, just a follow up question. I don't get the parameter "searchQuery". Can you give a sample on what I should input in that part?

Comment: The "searchQuery" is the name of the track, artist or album you want to search for. For instance, `Madonna`.